# How to change increasing series of numbers?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have the following table in PostgreSQL:

```
item   id
123    100-0001
123    100-0002
123    100-0003
.....
123    100-0150
```

I want to change the id of all records to match 745 till 894

meaning 100-0001 change to 100-0745, 100-0002 change to 100-746 etc.

the final result should be:

```
item   id
123    100-0745
123    100-0746
123    100-0747
.....
123    100-0894
```

id is of type `citext`.

How can I do that?

Note: table contains more records, they shouldn't be effected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd break the string up - the first four characters shouldn't be changed (`100-`). The second part can be converted to an integer, summed with 744 to get the new value, and padded back to four characters:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    id = SUBSTR(id, 0, 5) || 
            LPAD((SUBSTR(id, 5)::integer + 744)::varchar, 4, '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

With `row_number()` and a `join` in an `update` statement:

```
update t
    set id = '100-' || lpad(seqnum, 4, '0')
    from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by item order by id) as seqnum
          from t
         ) tt
    where t.id = tt.id;
```

Comment: This is overly complicated and will perform worse.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . This produces sequential id in the results, even if there are gaps in the original ids.